# Google Map on Android in a Tab

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, search, android-mapview

I am trying to make an application in which there are few tabs & one of the tab contains map.

Till now I was able to create the tabs and map on one of the tab. So when I click on the 1st tab I can see the map which shows a default city (Las Vegas).

My question is if now I want to create the same menu items (Search, Directions, Places etc.) which already exists in the default Google Map application in the emulator, Do I need to write the logic for all those menu items?

Its like I want the whole google map application in one of my tab. Is it possible?

I have created the map with zoom-in / zoom-out functionality. Now I want to add the search feature which will search for the place and locate it on the map. So do I need to write the whole code and ui for it? I am feeling like its re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to write the logic for all those menu items... the google maps api gives you all the tools to make it, like the map itself, overlays, items, itemized overlays, geocoding, etc. But the higher level functionalitys must be writed by you, using the tools mentioned above.